# Combine two SQL Queries to prevent having to use a loop

Tags: sql

I need to combine two SQL Queries and I'm hurting myself trying to think through it.  My first query gets the number of visitors per day and the second query gets the number of unique visitors per day.

**Query 1** - *For getting the number of visits*

```
SELECT Count(server_instances.game_id)  AS visit_count, 
       refined_player_visits.visit_date AS visit_date 
FROM   work.refined_player_visits 
       INNER JOIN tapi.server_instances 
               ON server_instances.server_id = refined_player_visits.server_id 
WHERE  ( server_instances.game_id = "31" ) 
GROUP  BY visit_date;
```

**Query 2** - *For getting the number of unique visits*

```
SELECT Count(visit_counts.unique_visit_date) AS unique_visits 
FROM   (SELECT Count(refined_player_visits.server_id) AS visit_count, 
               refined_player_visits.visit_date       AS unique_visit_date 
        FROM   refined_player_visits 
               INNER JOIN server_instances 
                       ON server_instances.server_id = 
                          refined_player_visits.server_id 
        WHERE  ( server_instances.place_id = "31" 
                 AND refined_player_visits.visit_date <= CURRENT_VISIT_DATE ) 
        GROUP  BY refined_player_visits.roblox_id) AS visit_counts 
WHERE  ( visit_counts.visit_date = CURRENT_VISIT_DATE 
         AND visit_counts.visit_count = 1 )
```

Because this was originally for a web application, I got the results back from the first query and looped through each one.  During each loop I would do the second query (where `CURRENT_VISIT_DATE` is actually the `visit_date` from the first query.

I'd like to turn this into one query using a `JOIN`, perhaps.  I'm migrating to another system and I don't have the option of doing a second query in the loop statement, so I want to just combine the two queries.  I can't seem to wrap my head around it, though.

Comment: Can you provide a sqlfiddle.com data sample?

Answer (score 0):

Does this return what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
     SELECT Count(server_instances.game_id)  AS visit_count, 
            refined_player_visits.visit_date AS visit_date 
     FROM   work.refined_player_visits 
     INNER JOIN tapi.server_instances 
         ON server_instances.server_id = refined_player_visits.server_id 
     WHERE  ( server_instances.game_id = "31" ) 
     GROUP  BY visit_date 
     ) AS FirstQuery,
    (
    SELECT Count(visit_counts.unique_visit_date) AS unique_visits 
    FROM   (SELECT Count(refined_player_visits.server_id) AS visit_count, 
                   refined_player_visits.visit_date       AS unique_visit_date 
            FROM   refined_player_visits 
                   INNER JOIN server_instances 
                           ON server_instances.server_id = 
                              refined_player_visits.server_id 
            WHERE (server_instances.place_id = "31" 
                  AND refined_player_visits.visit_date <= FirstQuery.visit_date) 
            GROUP  BY refined_player_visits.roblox_id) AS visit_counts 
    WHERE  ( visit_counts.visit_date = FirstQuery.visit_date
             AND visit_counts.visit_count = 1 )
    ) AS SecondQuery
```